# What to do if malloc returns NULL?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

in my program I work with big amount of data. I use the malloc() function to allocate memory for my large array. After I allocate the memory, I check if the pointer is NULL (that's because there isn't that big memory space or I don't know why).

But sometimes my pointer is NULL. So now what to do? I made a loop, that tries to allocate it again and again if the pointer is NULL. But it becomes to an infinite loop and it still says, that the pointer is NULL. So how to allocate the memory if it doesn't want to?

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Which language are you using, C or C++?  Tag just one.

Comment: Generally speaking, if malloc fails, it's not going to magically succeed just because you call it again. It will only succeed if you free up memory for it.

Comment: if malloc returns null then its probably failed for some reason, in this case you should log the error and exit

Comment: try allocating less memory? Check Your program with Valgrind or some similar checker for memory-leaks?

Comment: Try `malloc_harder()`

Comment: If `malloc` fails, you must have some serious memory leaks in your program. Typically the only reasonable thing to do upon detecting this is to exit gracefully.

Comment: Chances are you need to change your design to allocate smaller blocks of memory.  If you request a giant chunk of memory, `malloc` is required to find such a block of _contiguous_ memory.  If there is none available, it fails.  Over time, memory tends to become fragmented, so it becomes harder to find these chunks.  If you are able to design your program in a way that can utilise lots of smaller (say, 16MB) chunks instead of one giant (e.g. 2GB) chunk, you'll have more luck.  But yes, as others say, if the memory is not available, repeatedly asking for it will not work.

Comment: Go C++, call `operator new` and the returned pointer will never be `nullptr` (unless you are going for the `std::nothrow` route).

Comment: Normally, `NULL` is a macro with a _null pointer constant_. Thus a pointer variable cannot be `NULL`. However, it may be a _null pointer_ which equals `NULL`.

Comment: I'm programming in C on my laptop (where I also run the program). My allocated memory can be up to 100Kb big - which is, I think, not that much.

Comment: Unless you can free your own unused memory, or get a bigger heap from the OS, the only way out is to fail gracefully. You might have unsaved data, and at the very least, issue a red error message rather than a segfault.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the criticality of the memory you try to allocate:

- if the program can't run without it, just log the error and shutdown;
- if the program can run without it, and if it makes sense to run in degraded mode, log the error, drop the treatment and continue hoping for the best.

Answer (score 3):

If `malloc` fails then you have run out of available memory. 
There is no point in calling it again with the same requested size. It will continue to fail until you release some of your allocated memory using `free`.

Comment: In a multi-threaded environment, a second call might very well succeed.

Comment: True @Olaf, but if the OP hasn't got the hang of malloc and free then I doubt they are writing multi-threaded code.

Comment: And the point still stands. Someone has to call free - even if it might be a different thread.

Comment: Sure, but in that case, a loop in one thread might even succeed. Although I agree with your doubt. OP is collection oxygen in deep space.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on an embedded system that has limited memory, good chances are that the malloc() returned a NULL because you were attempting to request more memory than it had free (in one contiguous block).  Without knowing more implementation details, or the size of malloc() request, I cannot speculate about why this was.

However, it does point to the fact that you have to understand the memory utilization of your solution, so that you can determine what memory is being used where, and determine how you can free memory that might be in use, or if you have to move to a system design with more system memory.

Comment: That is not necessarily true. Especially on RAM-limited systems, there might be enough free memory, but non of the requested size. This is called fragmentation. However, the question cannot be answered. How should we know what his program should do?

Comment: @Olaf Did you seriously just downvote me because I didn't specify contiguous memory?

Comment: If that was the only issue, I would have removed the DV after yor edit. Problem is, the question cannot be answered to OPs satisfaction, because the only  correct answer would be: "You cannot." If you don't have potatoes you cannot make mashed potatoes.

Comment: If the point of having a forum for I.T. professionals to post questions to is to provide **useful** answers, then mine doesn't do a half bad job.  It points to understanding the underlying issue better, which is **why don't I have the memory available for a malloc()**.  This is a very common issue for embedded developers.  Understanding why it happens is the #1 step in resolving it.

Comment: Actually, system memory is usually not the limiting factor. It's more often than not address space. Virtual memory management is an important detail you need to address in your answer. Otherwise the closing sentence is close to wrong.

Comment: System memory IS normally the limiting factor on an embedded system, which is what @J.Murray was describing.

Comment: @IInspectable That's assuming that the solution is running an OS that supports Virtual memory management.  Many Embedded OS do not.  Without more details, I left the description High-level so not to cloud the underlying issue: Where's the memory being used?

Comment: @GrahamS: How does *"big amount of data"* and embedded (in the sense you are using the ambiguous term) go together? A smart phone is a common embedded system. All of the three leading smart phone OS's use virtual memory management. Picking an arbitrary setup that most likely doesn't match the OP's system specifications is not very useful.

Comment: @IInspectable And neither does imposing your own dispositions on the thread.  Without more information, _we don't know_.  And the embedded microcontroller world outstrips all smartphones on the face of the Earth by a magnitude of x100+.

Comment: @IInspectable the OP mentioned in the comments that he is limited to a 100KB heap. It's not unreasonable to think that they might be developing for an embedded system. But without more details from the OP all we can do is guess. So I think J.Murray's point is perfectly valid.

Comment: @IInspectable Unless you suspect that they are using C / C++ to develop a native application _for a SmartPhone._

Comment: @GrahamS: The OP mentioned in comments that they are *"programming in C on [their] laptop (where [they] also run the program)"*. If you consider a laptop an embedded system, then all the more reason to assume virtual memory management. At any rate, you have the last word. I've wasted enough time here already.

Comment: @IInspectable actually reading it again I think the OP means his *requested* size is 100KB not his available heap. In which case you are right, his OS will most likely supply virtual memory and his program must leak like a sieve!

Comment: Embedded developers just don't ask questions like this - they already know how their memory system works and how to debug it.

Comment: @MartinJames: Hmm, you are on SO for quite some time and still think people working with embedded systems always know what they do? (Notice I did not write "programmers or even developers ;-)